# SQLSRV PDO Driver adding extra character to integers

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm running IIS7 on a **`Windows Server 2008 R2 server with PHP5.4 and SQLSRV`** installed.

The basic problem is that when I try to retrieve certain values, extra/unknown characters are added to the returned value.

```
$options = array(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);
$this->db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$host;Database=$dbname",$user,$pass,$options);

$this->stmt =$this->connection->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL, PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED));
$this->stmt->execute();

$this->obj = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
$this->obj->$column;
```

Where `$column` is something such as "`ID`".

When I run a var_dump on the returned value, it reads out `string(4) "455"`. If I have $strB set to `"455", $strA == $strB` evaluates to false...

I've tried `iconv and utf8_decode` on the returned value, as well as setting different `PDO` encodings, all with no success.

The database collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue apparently had to do with setting the cursor...

```
$this->stmt =$this->connection->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL, PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED));
```

After removing the cursor settings from the options array, the unknown characters went away.

Answer (score 0):

I did so:

```
$serverName = "mySrv";
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=mySrv;Database=AdventureWorks", "myUser","mypass");

$db->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);                         
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$tsql = "Select num from myTable";
$stmt = $db->prepare($tsql);

$stmt->execute();

$fun = $stmt->fetch();  

echo gettype($fun['num'])."<br>";
var_dump($fun['num']);
```

Result:

```
integer
int(496)
```